# intellij not implying "this" keyword

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a field that I am changing through a method. If I do `this.myField=5` then the field is changed. But if I do `myField=5` the field is not changed. Is there a way I can set in the preferences for intellij to imply the `this` directive even if it is not present? I am importing a bunch of files from another IDE and changing each one of them is overkill.

```
//this fails to change myField in IntelliJ
public class MyClass{
  int myField;

  public void changeMyField(int x){
    myField=x;
  }
}

//this SUCCEEDS to change myField in IntelliJ
public class MyClass{
  int myField;

  public void changeMyField(int x){
    this.myField=x;
  }
}
```

Comment: That's not an intellij thing, that's a basic Java thing.  If you don't have a local variable called `myField`, your code should either modify the instance variable or give you a compiler error that you haven't defined it.

Comment: Let me guess, this is a constructor and one of your arguments is named `myField` ? :)

Comment: Language semantics is not an IDE setting. If it's broken in IDEA it must be just as broken in any other tool.

Comment: Again, are you sure it's not something like: `public void changeMyField(int myField){
        myField=myField;
    }` ?

Comment: I seriously doubt that that is the code you're having problems with. Post some *actual* code that exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: Both versions will work just fine, did you post the exact same code that failed to update ?

Comment: There's no way that the example you've given won't update the instance variable.  I think you've simplified your problem out of existence in the code you've posted.  Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Although, with the correctly failing code, I would expect that IDEA would display an in-line warning message (a setting?), as ReSharper does.

Comment: @user2864740 it won't display inline warning message but it will mark the line `myField=myField;` in grey, which means that this line is redundant and doesn't have any affect on the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is probably happening is your parameter to your function is named the same name as the field you want to change.  When you have a parameter named the same as an instance variable, the parameter will overshadow the instance variable, making it, in effect, inaccessible without using "this".

As azurefrog pointed out this is a Java thing and thus, you cannot change this behavior via any intelliJ setting.

Comment: Yep! I overlooked that. Duh!! I cannot accept now (must wait 8 minutes) and have to run to meeting. So I will accept later. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, good luck  :)